# How to clip multiple masks to one single fixed background?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to design a snippet where I have multiple elements reveling one common background behind them. Both circles have different opacity. They can move to show different parts of background.
I'm stuck and running out of ideas. How to approach this?

I'm trying to make the result look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image used as background:

[image]

Two circles are used as an SVG mask.
Different transparency of the circles is provided by the different transparency of the alpha channel for the components of the composite mask.

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 800 664" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
  <mask id="msk" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" /> 
     <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.4)" cx="280" cy="300" r="150" />
      <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)" cx="420" cy="300" r="120" />
  </mask>
</defs>    
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<image mask="url(#msk)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>   
</div>
```

To make the background a little visible, add to the mask

`<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#A96667" />`

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 800 664" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<defs>
  <mask id="msk" > 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#A96667" /> 
    <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" cx="280" cy="300" r="150" />
      <circle fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.6)" cx="420" cy="300" r="120" />
  </mask>
</defs>    
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<image mask="url(#msk)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WicJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>   
</div>
```

*The app is responsive and works the same in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, MS Edge.*

Answer (score 2):

mask is what you need:

```css
.box {
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  -webkit-mask:
    /*                 control the opacity --v              position / size */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 96%,#0000) 20% 50% / 300px 300px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 96%,#0000) 70% 50% / 200px 200px,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  background:#000;
}


html {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/800) top/cover
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Firefox is not combining the overlapping part of the circles. 'mask-composite: exclude' does not seem to give the desired results when the two elements are overlapping. However, everything works perfectly on the browsers using WebKit.

Comment: @AshutoshGulta yes I didn't notice that, will try to fix it

Comment: One last question @Temani. In case I need to use multiple images as mask instead of gradients, how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AshutoshGupta you keep the same structure and your replace `radial-gradient()` by `url()`

Comment: `.box {
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  -webkit-mask:
    url(mask.png) 10% 20% / 100px ,
    url(mask2.png) 40% 20% / 150px ;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  background:grey;
}` @TemaniAfif am I doing something wrong here? Also, how do I set the alpha values here in images?

Answer (score 0):

Setting same background for both divs seperately and moving background of elements according to their position.

```css
#container {
  background: #000;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.window {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624558481209-0e23e79e3872?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTYyNTg0OTY4NQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.one {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 250px;
  top: 140px;
  background-position: -250px -140px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.two {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
  background-position: -80px -80px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="window one"></div>
  <div class="window two"></div>
</div>
```